# Как с помощью С++ прочитать все текстовые  файлы в указанной папке?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как с помощью С++ прочитать все текстовые файлы в указанной папке? Имена файлов неизвестны.

Comment: Стандартным образом (Posix) [читать все файлы](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Directory-Lister.html) и анализировать каждый.

Comment: спс, а если нужно использовать boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда нужно зайти на сайт буста и за 2 минуты найти подходящий пример.
boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows есть функции WinAPI: FindFirstFile/FindNextFile, ищут файлы по маске: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Так же есть _findfirst/_findnext : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzxfzac.aspx

В POSIX системах есть функция glob.

Answer (score 0):

Вот когда то разработал класс для себя. Поиск файлов.
Он возвращает пути всех файлов, а после их можно прочесть.

Вот код:

```
#include<string>
#include<direct.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;






//class==========================================================
//Автор:Писанка Юрій
//Призначення: Пошук файлів і папок
//Примітка розроблено християнином
//Версія 1.1

#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

#include<Windows.h>

/*
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
*/

struct files_struct
{
    std::string URL;
    std::vector<std::string>Name;
};



class FILES_SCANER
{
public:
    //FILES_SCANER(void);
    //files_struct get_spisok_file(std::string URL,std::string Tip); //Пошук файлів у папці
    //void get_global_spisok_file(std::string url, std::string type); //Сканує ФС в паці і папках папок  файли Рекурсивно
    //char* transform_str(char* s, int (*fp)(int));
    //void User_get_global_spisok_file(std::string url, std::string type); //Сканує ФС в паці і папках папок  файли Рекурсивно Версія з очисткою
    //~FILES_SCANER(void);

std::vector<std::string>List;



FILES_SCANER::FILES_SCANER(void)
{

}



files_struct  FILES_SCANER::get_spisok_file(std::string URL,std::string Tip) //Пошук файлів у папці
{
    //cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<URL.c_str();

files_struct RT;
RT.URL = URL;

    if(URL.size()>=256) //Обійти Помилкову папку, файли стають невидимі
        return RT;




WIN32_FIND_DATA file; 
HANDLE hfile; 
char szpath[MAX_PATH]; 
strcpy(szpath,URL.c_str());
lstrcat(szpath,Tip.c_str()); //Тип Файлу і шлях
hfile=FindFirstFile(szpath,&file); 
if(hfile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{ 
do 
{
    RT.Name.push_back(file.cFileName);
    //cout<<file.cFileName<<endl;
}
while(FindNextFile(hfile,&file)!=0); 
FindClose(hfile); 
} 


return RT;
}

void FILES_SCANER::User_get_global_spisok_file(std::string url, std::string type) //Сканує ФС в паці і папках папок  файли Рекурсивно Версія з очисткою
{
    List.clear();
    get_global_spisok_file(url,type);
}

void FILES_SCANER::get_global_spisok_file(std::string url, std::string type) //Сканує ФС в паці і папках папок  файли Рекурсивно
{
    int i  = 0;
    files_struct A = get_spisok_file(url,"\\*.*");
    while(A.Name.size()>i) 
    { 
        if(  A.Name[i][(A.Name[i].size()-1)] != '.'  ) //Мусоровідкидач
        {
        std::string TEMPS_ = A.URL;
        TEMPS_+='\\';
        TEMPS_+=A.Name[i];

           if(type.size() <= 1)
           {
               // std::remove(TEMPS_.c_str());// видалити
               //std::cout<<TEMPS_.c_str()<<std::endl;
               List.push_back(TEMPS_);
           }
           else
        {
            //std::cout<<TEMPS_<<endl;
           //====================================================================================================
            int IJ = TEMPS_.size()-1;
            std::string fileTypeTemp = "";
            std::string JJL = "";
            while(IJ > 0)
            {
                if(IJ>TEMPS_.size()-1)  break;


                JJL.push_back(TEMPS_[IJ]);
                if(TEMPS_[IJ] == '.'){ break;}
                IJ--;
            }





            int IJ1 = JJL.size()-1;
            while(IJ1 >= 0)
            {
                fileTypeTemp.push_back(JJL[IJ1]);
                IJ1--;
            }
            //
            char STR1[20000];
            std::strcpy(STR1,fileTypeTemp.c_str());

            char STR2[20000];
            std::strcpy(STR2,type.c_str());

            std::string STR_1 = transform_str(STR1, tolower);
            std::string STR_2 = transform_str(STR2, tolower);

           if(STR_1 == STR_2)
           {
               // std::remove(TEMPS_.c_str());// видалити
               //std::cout<<TEMPS_.c_str()<<std::endl;
               List.push_back(TEMPS_);
           }


            //std::cout<<transform_str(STR1, tolower).c_str()  <<"         "<< transform_str(STR2, tolower).c_str()<<std::endl;
            //=================================================================================================================
            }

        get_global_spisok_file(TEMPS_,type); //Запускаю функцію ще раз *рекцрсія
        }

        i++; 
    }
}

    //std::cout << transform_str(s, tolower) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << transform_str(s, toupper) << std::endl;
char* FILES_SCANER::transform_str(char* s, int (*fp)(int))  //зведення до нижнього і верхнього регістру
{

    char* res = s;

    while(*s) {

        *s = fp(*s);
        ++s;
    }

    return res;
}


FILES_SCANER::~FILES_SCANER(void)
{
}

};

//==========================================================================


int main(int arg,char **argc)
{
    FILES_SCANER File;

    //если нужно в папке и всех вложеных папках
    /*File.User_get_global_spisok_file("C:\\","*.txt"); //Сканировать папки и подпапки

    int i = 0;
    while(File.List.size()>i)
    {
        cout<<File.List[i].c_str()<<endl;
        i++;
    }*/


    //только в папке

    files_struct A = File.get_spisok_file  ("C:\\","*.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while(A.Name.size()>i)
    {
        cout<<A.Name[i].c_str()<<endl;
        i++;
    }




    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Я в том смысле что отправил сюда, перед этим скопировал из своей папки с своими библиотеками.

Comment: еще чуть чуть исправил чтобы все в одном файле было.